# Insert into a destination table if the source value is not there in destination table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert the data from a table to another table, but i am looking out for a query which can first look if source value is there in destination, if present the should not load.

Let say I have the below in source

```
ID|EMAIL|COUNTRY|PHONE
1|s@s.com|US|1212
```

Now check if the above email is present in the destination table, if not load it.

Awaiting for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MERGE` Statement

```
MERGE table2 AS target
USING table1 AS source
    ON (target.email = source.email)  
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (
        email, 
        country, 
        Phone
    ) VALUES (
        source.email, 
        source.country, 
        source.phone
    );
```

Comment: Does this insert the data from one table to another permanently

Comment: Yes, it does. It checks if the email from your source table already exists in your target table, if not, then it inserts it. If it already exists it does nothing.

Comment: Then edit the `INSERT` part to include those columns, see my updated answer.

Comment: You are using SQL Server 2008, are you not? I only forgot to add a semi-colon as you have to terminate a `MERGE` statement with that. Other then that it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Join will also do the job

```
INSERT INTO <TblDestination>
SELECT src.Email
FROM <TblSource> src
    LEFT JOIN <TblDestination> dst ON src.Email = dst.Email
WHERE dst.Email IS NULL
```